# How to pass space separated value as a single Argument to execute the java code from spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

ALL,

## update

I am trying to execute java code from spark by passing the argument(argument will have space separated value).
e.g.

```
arg4 = "country='USA' AND state='Newyork'"
```

my code will be like this:

```
spark-submit --jars <path>/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar \
--driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<path>/devjaas.conf" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./jaas_hdfs_dev.conf" \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--files <path>/jaas_hdfs_dev.conf,<credential> \
--executor-memory 10g \
--executor-cores 5 \
--driver-cores=5 \
--driver-memory=10G \
--conf spark.executor.cores=5 \
--conf spark.yarn.am.cores=5 \
--conf spark.yarn.am.memory=15g \
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 \
--class "<java class>" <jar file> $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
```

this is throwing as error because arg4 has space and code is not treat value of arg4 as a single argument. I am executing spark code inside shell script,I have passed all the values to the variable in shell script.

```
    arg1= "first"
    arg2="second"
    arg3="third"
    arg4="country='USA' AND state='Newyork'"
```

while executing shell script by sh -x , i do see value of arg4 in command line like this

```
'country='\''USA'\'' AND '\''state=NEWYORK'\'''
```

How can we handle this problem? can you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: using double quote `"country='USA' AND state='Newyork'"` not working?

Comment: @PatrickChen, yes it is not working

Comment: `--class "<java class>" <jar file> arg1, arg2,arg3, "arg4"` (double quote all arguments that contain spaces).

Comment: Can you post error message here ? & also post your main method how are you reading arguments ?

Answer (score 1):

We have to pass arguments separated by space to main class, Can you try passing arguments like below.

```
--class "<java class>" <jar file> arg1 arg2 arg3 "country='USA' AND state='Newyork'"
```

If you add comma `,` between arguments main class will treat those arguments as single value till it find space.

Try to put your arguments inside quotes. like below.

```
--class "<java class>" <jar file> "$arg1" "$arg2" "$arg3" "$arg4"
```

Comment: sorry there was space separated argument. It’s not working. and i have called all this things from shell script.

Comment: Can you post your shell script

Comment: I have updated answer & try to put all your arguments inside quotes - "$arg1" "$arg2" "$arg3" "$arg4"

Answer (score 1):

Java treats the set of all words between double quotes (") as one string.
Therefore, using double quotes will allow reading of space-separated list of words as one argument.

**Here is a working demo:**

```
// File name:  ShowArgs.java

public class ShowArgs {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        for (String s: args) {
            count++;
            System.out.println("arg # " + count + " : " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output #1 (Run the program from command line):**

```
$ javac ShowArgs.java

$ java ShowArgs arg1 arg2 arg3 "country='USA' AND state='Newyork'"

arg # 1 : arg1
arg # 2 : arg2
arg # 3 : arg3
arg # 4 : country='USA' AND state='Newyork'
```

**Output #2 (Run the program through shell script)**

```
$ export arg1="Hello!"
$ export arg2="How are you doing"
$ export arg3=", buddy?"
$ export arg4="country='USA' AND state='New York'"

$ java ShowArgs "$arg1" "$arg2" "$arg3" "$arg4"
arg # 1 : Hello!
arg # 2 : How are you doing
arg # 3 : , buddy?
arg # 4 : country='USA' AND state='New York'
```